# What perl version is required for dancer2?

Tags: perl, dancer

Godaddy supplies perl 5.8 on the "standard" unix share.  Before attempting to use Dancer2 I would like to know if 5.8 will suffice.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like it's meant to support 5.8, but [one test currently requires 5.10](http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/6939e71a-81cc-11e8-b18d-822462266ff8) for no reason. You might want to report it as a bug against Dancer2.

Comment: They are seriously supplying a version  which was released 12 years ago (5.8.8 according to [this](https://www.godaddy.com/help/perl-details-on-linux-shared-hosting-2503?)) and is long out of life? If the rest of their infrastructure and security is similar outdated you might better use a different provider.

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/PerlDancer/Dancer2/pull/1479 to fix the test issue. In the meantime you can install it using `cpan -Ti Dancer2` or `cpanm -n Dancer2`. But note that either way it will not be installable on Perls older than 5.8.8 due to the Template Toolkit requirement.

Comment: Also the prerequisite HTTP::XSCookies requires Perl 5.8.9, but it is not actually a requirement, I opened https://github.com/PerlDancer/Dancer2/pull/1480 to fix that issue.

Comment: It's super easy to install a newer version Perl in your home directory using `perlbrew`. And this would also make it easier to install modules

Answer (score 0):

A GoDaddy-wise comment: if you are trying to do this on a GoDaddy-hosted server and aren't running a dedicated server, it is doubtful they will upgrade the version of perl installed there on demand.

Comment: For various reasons I have decided to find a new provider.  Thank you all for your input.